# How to compare two rows in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've a `data.csv` file which looks as follows.

```
-1.95e+01   -2.30e-01   -2.56e-01   4.44e+01
-1.95e+01   -2.30e-01   -7.68e-01   4.48e+01
-2.00e+01   -2.30e-01   -2.56e-01   3.41e+01
-2.00e+01   -2.30e-01   -7.69e-01   3.46e+01
-2.10e+01   -9.92e+00   1.00e+01    9.66e+01
-2.10e+01   -9.92e+00   2.30e+00    4.29e+01
```

I'd like to have a `result.csv` file such that if the value in the first column is the same, grab all the data in the first four columns (there are 4 columns) and save it in `result.csv` file. Then the next equal values and save it in the next four columns. For example  my `result.csv` should look like

```
-1.95e+01 -2.30e-01 -2.56e-01 4.44e+01  -2.00e+01 -2.30e-01 -2.56e01 3.41e+01 -2.10e+01 -9.92e+00 1.00e+01 9.66e+01
-1.95e+01 -2.30e-01 -7.68e-01 4.48e+01  -2.00e+01 -2.30e-01 -7.69e-01 3.46e+01 -2.10e+01 -9.92e+00 2.30e+00 4.29e+01
```

My very basic attempt is as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for col in csv_reader:      
        i = 0
        if col[0] == "Next value of the same column": 'don't know how to fix
            #Grab all the values which have same value in the first column
        else:
            #Grab next values which have same value in the first column
        i += 1
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu, or Linux, or any operating system. It's a Python question.

Comment: @JayEye there are tons of python questions in **Ask Ubuntu**

Comment: that may be so, but it doesn't mean it's an appropriate place to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as _:
  input = csv.reader(_, delimiter='\t')
  output = [[]]
  previous_col0 = None
  line_n = 0
  for cols in input:
      if cols[0] == previous_col0: 
          line_n += 1
      else:
          previous_col0 = cols[0]
          line_n = 0 
      if len(output) <= line_n:
          output += [[]]
      output[line_n] += cols
```